# Extract x amount of characters before and after certain strings in column

Tags: r, string, vector, extract

I am trying to find a way to look for 10 words in every row within one column. For example:

```
words <- c('corona','covid','infection','positive','test','negative','result','antigen','covid19','unknown')
```

I have a df with 2 columns, 'ID' and 'comment' with about 2500 rows. Is there a way to search for all these 10 words at once within the 'comment' column and return an x amount of characters before and after these words? I would like to return the x amount of characters before to one column and the x amount of characters after to another column.

I hope this is clear.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your expected outcome? What you want to return if more words are found? Do you want to show them all with for each word x characters before and after, or do you want x characters before the first found word and x characters after the last found word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
library(stringr)

# Define the words to search for
words <- c('corona','covid','infection','positive','test','negative','result','antigen','covid19','unknown')

# Create a sample data frame
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:2500, comment = sample(c("This is a comment about covid.",
                                                 "Here no of your words is mentioned at all",
                                                 "Another comment with corona mentioned.", 
                                                 "There is a positive test for covid19."), 2500, replace = TRUE))

# define the number of characters to extract before and after the matched word
x <- 20

# create a dataframe to store the results
result_df <- data.frame(ID = df$ID)

# loop through each word and extract the characters before and after the word
for (word in words) {
  # extract the characters before and after the word
  before <- str_extract(df$comment, paste0(".{0,", x, "}", word))
  after <- str_extract(df$comment, paste0(word, ".{0,", x, "}"))
  
  # store the results in the result_df
  result_df[[paste0("before_", word)]] <- before
  result_df[[paste0("after_", word)]] <- after
}

# merge the result dataframe with the original dataframe
result_df <- merge(df, result_df)

# print the result dataframe
result_df
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `dplyr` and `stringr`, more specifically using `str_locate` to get the matches and `str_sub` to extract the *before* and *after* strings. Also excluding spaces around the matched word. Multiple matches get additional lines.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # for unnest()
library(stringr)

rnge <- 10

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(loc = list(as_tibble(str_locate(comment, wd)))) %>% 
  unnest(loc) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(start) | row_number() == 1, .by = ID) %>% 
  mutate(before = str_sub(comment, start - (!!rnge + 1), start - 2), 
         after = str_sub(comment, end + 2, end + (!!rnge + 1))) %>% 
  arrange(ID, start) %>% 
  filter(!(duplicated(comment) & is.na(start))) %>% 
  select(-c(start, end))
# A tibble: 11 × 4
      ID comment                                       before     after       
   <int> <chr>                                         <chr>      <chr>       
 1     1 The friendly gang left the drug store.        e friendly "left the d"
 2     1 The friendly gang left the drug store.        endly gang "the drug s"
 3     2 A small creek cut across the field.           NA          NA         
 4     3 The beauty of the view stunned the young boy. f the view "the young "
 5     4 The walled town was seized without a fight.   NA          NA         
 6     5 The soft cushion broke the man's fall.        NA          NA         
 7     6 The bill was paid every third week.           e bill was "every thir"
 8     7 The rope will bind the seven books at once.   NA          NA         
 9     8 The swan dive was far short of perfect.       NA          NA         
10     9 A yacht slid around the point into the bay.   around the "into the b"
11    10 Always close the barn door tight.             NA          NA
```

##### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, comment = c("The friendly gang left the drug store.", 
"A small creek cut across the field.", "The beauty of the view stunned the young boy.", 
"The walled town was seized without a fight.", "The soft cushion broke the man's fall.", 
"The bill was paid every third week.", "The rope will bind the seven books at once.", 
"The swan dive was far short of perfect.", "A yacht slid around the point into the bay.", 
"Always close the barn door tight.")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

wd <- c("left", "stunned", "paid", "point", "black", "gang")
```